# Spark create multiple Data frames from one Data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark 2.1 with Cassandra (3.9) as data source. C* has a big table with 50 columns, which is not a good data model for my use case. so I created split tables for each of those sensors along with partition key and clustering key cols.

```
All sensor table
-----------------------------------------------------
| Device |   Time     | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Sensor3 |
|  dev1  | 1507436000 |  50.3   |    1    |    1    |
|  dev2  | 1507436100 |  90.2   |    0    |    1    |
|  dev1  | 1507436100 |  28.1   |    1    |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------
Sensor1 table
-------------------------------
| Device |   Time     | value |
|  dev1  | 1507436000 | 50.3  |
|  dev2  | 1507436100 | 90.2  |
|  dev1  | 1507436100 | 28.1  |
-------------------------------
```

Now I am using spark to copy data from old table to new ones.

```
df = spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="allsensortables", keyspace="dataks")\
    .load().cache()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
query = ('''select device,time,sensor1 as value from data  ''' )
vgDF = spark.sql(query)
vgDF.write\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="sensor1", keyspace="dataks")\
    .save()
```

copying data one by one is taking a lot of time (2.1) hours for a single table. is there any way i can `select *` and create multiple df for each sensors and save at once ? (or even sequentially).

Comment: How are you running your code using spark-shell command ??

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde using spark-submit

Comment: Ok @Junaid, Try to increase driver memory and executor memory. It will help you.

Comment: current conf is --executor-memory 10G --num-executors=2 --executor-cores=4. using gce 8cpu 30gb ram 3 instances

Answer (score 0):

One issue in the code is the cache

```
df = spark.read\
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
.options(table="allsensortables", keyspace="dataks")\
.load().cache()
```

Here I don't see how df is used multiple times apart from save. SO here cache is counter productive. You are reading the data, filter it and saving it to a separate cassandra table. Now the only action happening on the dataframe is the save and nothing else.

So there is no benefit from caching the data here. Removing the cache will give you some speed up.

To create multiple tables sequentially. I would suggest to use partitionBy and write the data first to HDFS as partitioned data w.r.t sensor and then write it back to cassandra.

Comment: thanks, will remove the cache and test. let me try hdfs and partitionBy .also there is c* side filtering available in connector but I am not sure how it can be used in python. if select is added it says object has no attribute 'select'.  https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md

Comment: Yes, cassandra allows predicate pushdown. Not sure whether the lib present in the python also